# Fiddle me this - Sounds good

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, knowledge

> I think of an unlucky traveler,
>   The arguably greatest one ever.
>
> Indeed, from Munster now she's far away,
>   She'd be by now over 200 years.
>
> Her only target was the big apple,
>   Oh, but how the fog did detain her.
>
> On her way she went, with a zoo,
>   Plus Barney, Jimmy and the crew.
>
> Eve of the 8th year, a huge rock did hit her,
>   Released all the bones, and her trip was over.

The answer is a name.

Comment: This is my fist puzzle here, and English is not my first language. Any feedback appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's

> The Irish Rover

The clues are basically

> lyrics from the song

Not quite clear about the opening, maybe it's just a general description of the rest:

I think of an unlucky traveler / The arguably greatest one ever.

Or it could be a reference to

> We'd an elegant craft, it was rigged 'fore and aft / And how the trade winds drove her / She had twenty-three masts and she stood several blasts

Indeed, from Munster now she's far away /
She'd be by now over 200 years.

> In the year of our Lord, eighteen hundred and six / We set sail from the Coal Quay of Cork (Cork is in the province of Munster)

Her only target was the big apple, / Oh, but how the fog did detain her.

> She was bound "For the fine city hall of New York" .... "And the ship lost her way in a fog"

On her way she went, with a zoo,

> We had five million hogs, we had six million dogs

Plus Barney, Jimmy and the crew.

> There was Barney Magee from the banks of the Lee / There was Hogan from County Tyrone / There was Johnny McGurk who was scared stiff of work ....

Eve of the 8th year,

> We had sailed seven years when the measles broke out / And our ship lost her way in a fog

a huge rock did hit her

> Then the ship struck a rock

Not sure about the bones, might be

> in a different version of the song.

Comment: Good answer! How do you think the fact that rot13(svefg yrggref fcryy "vg vf ubbcre") ties into this?

Comment: Perfect! Congratulations! rot13(Gur obarf ner sebz n qvssrerag irefvba, vaqrrq: "Jr unq sbhe zvyyvba oneeryf bs obarf". Gur gvgyr jnf n uvag gung vg'f n fbat. Naq nyfb vs lbh ernq gur svefg yrggre bs gur 1fg yvar, gur ynfg yrggre bs gu 2aq yvar, gur svefg bs gur 3eq, naq fb ba... Lbh trg: VEVFU EBJRE)

Comment: @BálintBudavölgyi Does this mean my observation was a coincidence?

Comment: rot13(Vg jnf vagragvbanyyl, ohg gb or zvfyrnqvat n ovg. Ubjrire gurer jrer nobhg 13 zvyyvba oneeryf ba gur fuvc, fb gurl arrqrq n srj tbbq ubbcref (zrnavat: na byq snfuvbarq jbeq sbe n crefba jub znxrf be ercnvef pnfxf naq oneeryf).)

Comment: Mick - may I suggest adding a link to Wikipedia for the item in your first spoiler block? For those of us who don't know it (like me), it would be a small convenience. Reading that alongside your explanations was very helpful for me.